# Enlarge matrix repeating its values

Tags: matlab, matrix, remap

I need to enlarge a matrix `A` to a matrix `B` with size `n` times the size of `A`. The values must be repeated, eg:

`A` size 2x3, `n` = 3, leads to `B` size 6x9:

Sample values:

```
A =  
1 2 3  
4 5 6
```

Results with:

```
B =  
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3    
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3  
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3  
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6  
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6   
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
```

What is the fastest way to achieve that in Matlab?

Comment: one more option is the `repelem` - repeat elements in an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can easily do this using `imresize` with nearest neighbor interpolation.

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];

% Repeat each element 3 times in each direction
B = imresize(A, 3, 'nearest');

%   1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
%   1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
%   1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
%   4     4     4     5     5     5     6     6     6
%   4     4     4     5     5     5     6     6     6
%   4     4     4     5     5     5     6     6     6
```

If you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use `interp2` with nearest neighbor interpolation to do something similar.

```
scaleFactor = 3;


[xx,yy] = meshgrid(linspace(1, size(A, 2), size(A, 2) * scaleFactor), ...
                   linspace(1, size(A, 1), size(A, 1) * scaleFactor));


B = interp2(A, xx, yy, 'nearest');
```

Comment: Check out [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)

Comment: @Dan, thanks I will.

Comment: @Pedro77 As far as speed, I think that `kron` is going to be hard to beat.

Answer (score 5):

There is also the Kronecker Tensor Product ([kron](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html)) function:

```
n = 3;
B = kron(A,ones(n));

B =

     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
     4     4     4     5     5     5     6     6     6
     4     4     4     5     5     5     6     6     6
     4     4     4     5     5     5     6     6     6
```

Comment: ah you beat me to it. Nice one!

Comment: These days you can just use the builtin [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) function

Comment: oh sweet I did not know about this one